# How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 . I used to try to install it into Ubuntu 11.10 as install on Ubuntu 11.04 but it doesn't work. Please anyone tell me how to install it into Ubuntu 11.10.

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/54547/install-eclipse-4-1-manually

Answer (score 17):

1. Download one of the available Eclipse bundles from the [official site](http://eclipse.org/downloads/). I got `eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
2. Extract it

   ```
   tar xzf eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```

   Or just be lazy and Right Click > Extract Here
3. Move to `/opt/` folder

   ```
   mv eclipse /opt/
   sudo chown -R root:root eclipse
   sudo chmod -R +r eclipse
   ```
4. Create an eclipse executable in your path

   ```
   sudo touch /usr/bin/eclipse
   sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/eclipse
   sudo nano /usr/bin/eclipse
   ```

   copy the following into /usr/bin/eclipse

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"
   export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"

   $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
   ```

   save the file (^O = Ctrl+o) and exit nano (^X = Ctrl+x)
5. Create a gnome menu item

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   copy the following into /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Eclipse
   Comment=Eclipse IDE
   Exec=eclipse
   Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
   StartupNotify=true
   ```

   save and exit nano
6. Launch Eclipse for the first time

   ```
   /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &
   ```

Comment: After executing command: /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &
this line is printed in terminal
/usr/bin/eclipse: 5: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: not found please respond to it.

Comment: because your first instruction did not work properly
you should put "sudo " befor that to access /usr/ from root
I mean that write this line instead of first line
sudo mv eclipse /opt/ then just type the last line again :
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean & I hope this will work :D

Comment: is there an implicit changing of directories after you move the "eclipse" folder into "opt"? Because subsequent chown & chmod commands don't have anything locally (or globally) to operate on.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think eclipse needs 'install', just extract(unpack) it and everything is ok.

Comment: Indeed - the first answer here lists an extended method to totally integrate it. Just extracting it and running the eclipse executable works too :)

Comment: -1: While this works, it's inconsistent with application installation on the Ubuntu platform. Moreover, platform tools aren't aware of its location, so things like launchers or uninstallers don't know about it out-of-the-box.