# Install eclipse without dependencies open-jdk

Tags: 11.10, java, eclipse

- I have Sun Java 7 installed on my ubuntu 11.10
- I want to install Eclipse but when I try installing eclipse, it will install open-jdk as well which I do not need at all
- Is there any way I can install eclipse without open-jdk.

Comment: download and install from eclipse.org

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1

Comment: tachyons thanks for pointing to a very detailed existing response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download it from the [Eclipse download website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
It's a zip file that you can extract to anywhere you want to have Eclipse.
No installation required.

Comment: and use alacarte to make a shortcut