# How do I install latest Eclipse Indigo in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)

I'm now using Eclipse 3.7.0 from Ubuntu Software Center but there's no option in Update Manager or USC to upgrade latest version Indigo SR2.

previously, I tried to search ppa from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/ppa) but eclipse team had not continued yet since Jaunty released

Can I get any ppas? and how do I install latest Eclipse Indigo in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

I personally install eclipse by downloading the latest version as .tar.gz from eclipse.org and extract it into my home directory ~/apps. This works quite well and allows me to update via Eclipse update feature. (Don't forget to remove the ubuntu package for eclipse)

I just need to add a menu entry to the eclipse binary: ~/app/eclipse/eclipse

No additional changes are needed it works out of the box.
Maybe this will also work for you.