# How to allow only one entry instance for Netbeans/Eclipse in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, eclipse, netbeans

I created a `netbeans.desktop` and `eclipse.desktop` and added them to **Unity launcher** and did exactly the same for eclipse & Netbeans here: [How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1) in order to run it from terminal or dashboard.
The problem is that if I run them from dashboard or terminal, another **entry** is displayed in the launcher.

[image: second Entry in Launcher]

Is there any solution so that when I run the IDEs from dashboard or terminal, only the Launcher entry already pinned, is used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use eclipse from software center.  i don't have a solution for netbeans, since i don't use it

Comment: @aking1012 For Eclipse case! I kept away from installing from SC because I have an eclipse which I deeply configured for my development needs. Reproducing these confs in a newly installed Eclipse is gonna take me time and I might not remember all what I did.

For Netbeans, I do need the latest version 7.1-2 which is not in SC.
Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I understand.  There are known bugs with Java programs and the launcher.  It isn't specific to software development environments, both of those programs are just written in Java.  Until it's okay to install from software center, I would recommend a)using an application launcher like the one from screenlets(I do) or b)installing from software center.  Short of that, I am sure the Canonical Devs/Ubuntu *unpaid* Community Maintainers are working as hard as they can.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I don't doubt about Devs work :)
I shall live now with the Launcher (I am installing eclipse from Software Center soon after I figure out all my custom tweakings). For Netbeans, Updating it to the latest version in USC is gonna be a big advantage for Ubuntu. Looking forward to that.

Answer (score 2):

Effective solution found thanks to Java Swing Ayatana library.

[image: Netbeans Integration with Global Menu and Launcher]

Open your Netbeans IDE, then go to menu: **Options / Plugins**; And add the Java Ayatana plugin's remote XML catalog file: `http://java-swing-ayatana.googlecode.com/files/netbeans-catalog.xml`
 and then install it - (Restart NetBeans).

- Illustration: http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/
- Credit: http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/