# eclipse install

Tags: 11.10, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)

I've already downloaded linux eclipse tar file from eclipse site as file named:`eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR2-incubation-linux-gtk.tar.gz`.

Now I want to install it in ubuntu 10.10. I'm new in ubuntu and linux. Would you tell me simply and step by step how can I install it?
Thanks

Clarification it's **Eclipse c++ Endigo**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any special thing; just extract from the archive to some directory and launch ./eclipse from there.

Comment: I did it. It returned "The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform". After I wrote "sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform" it re turned :"E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: Have you wrote "eclipse" or "./eclipse" in the terminal?

Comment: Also, the error "E: Could not ..." happens because another installation is running on the same moment (just wait) or apt-get is stuck(and now you need to fix this)

Comment: I  wrote "./eclipse /home/es/Desktop" in terminal. Now it returns : "No such file or directory"

Comment: cd /home/es/Desktop && ./eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The Process mentioned by Anton & Alvar is Correct, if it still not working then there may be two things

1>the downloaded file may be corrupted.

2>you don't have the file permission in that directory.

One more thing check JDK is installed on your system or not?

Comment: Permission isn't changeable. Do you know why?

Comment: Suppose you extracted archive file in /home/username/,then open terminal and goto /home/username/ and Try using sudo chmod -R 777 eclipse. i am sure it will work. Otherwise extract it again.

Comment: You should be on a administrator account. This might not work if you are on guest or standard account. Do all installation using the Administrator account.

Comment: Check JDK is working or not. OpenJDK also works fine. Commands are java and javac