# How to install Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)
>   [How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)

I downloaded the Eclipse setup from their homepage. And I followed the instructions on [this](http://flurdy.com/docs/eclipse/install.html) page. But I couldn't able to follow the last instruction, which ask me to do so :

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean
```

If do so, I get an error message like this :

```
sudo: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: command not found
```

But notably I can see the Eclipse Icon on my Dash Home (if I search for "Eclipse"). But clicking on that icon doesn't open the IDE. Where I'm making the mistake?

And also running this command in terminal :

```
eclipse
```

throws this output:

```
/usr/bin/eclipse: 5: /usr/bin/eclipse: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: Permission denied
```

Thanks in advance.