# Will eclipse update from the ubuntu repositories?

Tags: 12.04, java, repository, eclipse, official-repositories

If I install a default eclipse from the ubuntu program central, I get an eclipse with traces from the version Helios and the screen that starts Eclipse says Indigo. The latest version of Eclipse is called Juno. It's possible to download a separate download of eclipse juno and run it and link as mentioned:

[How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)

But the Eclipse available from the central ubuntu reposotiries could update to version 4 (Juno) and then we would not have to do the manual install. Or how do I update a manual install? I can't update the default install to Juno.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/438153/

This is the version we get from the ubuntu repositories and it can't be updated to Eclipse Juno, something is b0rked in "Object Teams Patch":

Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Help->Check for Updates in Eclipse Juno. This will check for updates from Eclipse.org. But this will not upgrade.

Comment: Yes but the current version of Eclipse we get via the ubuntu program manager is only 3.7 and has Helios components. Isn't best to update the central Eclipse that we get via ubuntu program central so not everybpdy has to do a manual install of Juno?

Comment: actually for eclipse there is not manual installation you just have to download extract and then run. Developers in my company they all use this kind of update with manual installation. So I think best way to do is taking updates from Eclipse site for Eclipse. They are more accurate and more upto-date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the Android SDK and Eclipse (ADT Bundle) from [this site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download). Unzip the file and run the Eclipse file from there. Make sure it is executable and you'll have the latest version of Eclipse and a working update mechanism.

Comment: he is not asking for android SDK isn't it ?

Comment: The android developer site provides One download for the SDK and Eclipse. He may delete the SDK folder if he doesn't need it.

Comment: he can directly download from eclipse site why should he download it from android site