# Not able to install Eclipse from ubuntu software center

Tags: eclipse

While i try to install Eclipse from ubuntu software center, it prompts me that `failed to download packages` and `check your internet connection`. If I click on `OK` button, it gives me `requires installation of untrusted packages` and in the details option:

```
ant ant-optional default-jdk default-jre default-jre-headless eclipse-jdt 
eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar 
gcj-4.6-base gcj-4.6-jre-lib jarwrapper junit junit4 libart-2.0-2 libasm3-java 
libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libcommons-
beanutils-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-
compress-java libcommons-digester-java libcommons-el-java libcommons-
httpclient-java libcommons-logging-java libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.1-java 
libdb5.1-java-gcj libecj-java libequinox-osgi-java libgcj-bc libgcj-common 
libgcj12 libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common 
libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libhamcrest-java libicu4j-4.4-java libicu4j-java 
libjasper-java libjaxp1.3-java libjline-java libjsch-java libjtidy-java 
liblucene2-java libregexp-java libservlet2.4-java libslf4j-java libxerces2-java 
sat4j
```

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection and retried, as software center prompted? This is a huge download, so it is not unlikely that there was a (temporary) outage at some point.

Comment: yes,i checked and retried several times on several days

Comment: Isn't there a "Repair" button when it tells you that it has to install "untrusted packages"?

Comment: @jobin there is "No Repair" button

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the download mirror. and if possible, manually download **Eclipse** from eclipse site and download **jdk** from Oracle. and then edit the eclipse.ini and add this line at the very beginning

```
-vm
/path_to_your_jdk/bin
```

that would give you a much better performance

Comment: Anam, please explain why that would give a much better performance.

Comment: First of all, downloading eclipse from eclipse.org will ensure the latest build. and another thing is, eclipse from software center will download *openjdk* which is incompatible with some eclipse plugins.

Comment: I agree with downloading Eclipse from eclipse.org, though not for performance reasons. Regarding OpenJDK, I am not aware of any _recent_ incompatibility or performance issues in combination with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your software sources and disable those that aren't trusted. All required packages are in the Ubuntu archives (assuming you are on 12.04+), so you shouldn't need to install untrusted packages to install Eclipse.

---

Personally I prefer to not install Eclipse via the Software Centre (or apt-get). Eclipse has no system dependencies apart from the presence of a Java SE 5+ runtime, so I just download Eclipse off eclipse.org, unzip  and run. To uninstall, `rm -rf`. All of this as user, not as root.

On Ubuntu, obviously I **do** install the default-jdk package to have Java.

Comment: Note that the advice to download Eclipse from eclipse.org may or may not help solve the 'untrusted packages' issue, depending on whether the untrusted package is Eclipse or the JDK (or its dependencies).

Comment: No i am on ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Then I would install the JDK using the package manager, and install Eclipse from a download. This is the advice that many others on Askubuntu give as well. See, e.g. [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1).

Comment: Looking at the first answer to the question I linked to above: don't do that. It installs Eclipse root-owned in `/opt`. There is no need or reason to do that. Just unzip the downloaded archive somewhere in your home directory. That's all.