# Installing Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I downloaded "eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz"

How do I install it in the Operating System Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Please check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1

Comment: This question has been asked before: [How to install Eclipse?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26632/62483) You can install your mentioned file using the method mentioned in [one answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/145018/62483) of my link.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, you extract the file to a directory then run the executable file located in the directory, `eclipse`.

I have my running out of the `Downloads` directory under the folder `eclipse`. It's all Java based itself, so it doesn't require an actual installation to anywhere but your user folder in linux. On first run it will ask your for the `workspace` folder in your user directory, select it. Then to move to another machine just copy this folder and the workspace folder and run there, your good to go.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM

Answer (score 0):

`tar xvzf eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz -C ~/`.
Then go to you extracted files and double click `eclipse` or run from terminal `./eclipse`. Be sure to execute the command within the directory of extracted files. If errors occur run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-doc`.
I forgot to type: it doesn't need to be installed.