# Can I use the previous instructions for the new Eclipse installation?

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and would like to install it; I have seen a similar installation issue in "[How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)". But I'm not sure if following the instructions step by step would be a successful effort for my case.

Can someone present explanation or question link of a version-independent instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the steps from "[How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1](https://askubuntu.com/a/89430/230948)". From eclipse perspective this is completely version independent.