# Eclipse install from USC fails

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I selected Eclipse from within USC and clicked the 'Use this source' button. The 'Progress' icon whirls for a few seconds, and then I get a message box:

Failed to download repository information

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::17 80]
```

Why won't it download?

Comment: I have no control over the 'sources list'. All I can do is click on the icon in the USC.

Comment: sources.list is a file located at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and owned by root. You can open the sources.list file for editing from the terminal using the command: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

On this server, there are no packages for Quantal more. Update your Ubuntu installation. Update at least to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

In your case, download Eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers-442/lunasr2) and then follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/89430/367165)  or use the new [Eclipse Installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: OK, I found the instructions - I'll jump through the hoops
Thanks!

Comment: @user3063708 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: In and of itself, your answer is pretty straightforward. However, it leaves me neck deep in the morass of instructions on how to upgrade Ubuntu.

Why don't they just have a file you can download and say 'run that'. Geez, what a kludgy process.

Comment: I can only give one answer for one question.

Comment: For an update, there are many answers here in AskUbuntu.

Comment: "Why don't they..." is rhetorical. 
I should just say 'They should have a file...etc'

Comment: I think, you should download Eclipse here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers-442/lunasr2. Don't use USC

Comment: Answer updated.