# Eclipse is not running after installation

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 today. I need to install eclipse on it. I followed this link ([How do I install Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1)) and completely did all what were said. When I want to start it for first time, I receive following error:

```
bash: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: No such file or directory
```

My installed eclipse files and folders structure is:

```
.   artifacts.xml  eclipse-inst      features  p2       readme
..  configuration  eclipse-inst.ini  icon.xpm  plugins
```

I'm sure that java is installed properly and both eclipse and OS are 64x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you've installed Eclipse Neon, not Eclipse Indigo, which is a good thing.  In any case, what you've installed is just the installer program.  You have to run "eclipse-inst" to actually install Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I'm trying it. Please let me try the Indigo, then I will get back. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, whatever. Installing Indigo would generally be a mistake. Use the latest, which is Neon, unless there are specific plugins that only work with Indigo.

Comment: Ok, please let me try again installing Neon, Thanks for invaluable advise.